# Connect the MySQL server kept in OpenShift cloud through MySql.Data.MySqlClient method

Tags: c#, mysql, openshift

I have created mysql server in Openshift cloud and created one database table. Now i want to connect the mysql server from my Asp.net application. I have tried with MySql.Data.MySqlClient method(C#). Please help me if there is any syntax error in my connection string.
Below given the connection string sample:

```
string connnectionString = "server=x.x.x.x:(port);user id=xxx; password=yyyy; database=iac; pooling=true";
```

Comment: Cursory glance looks OK. However, what does "I have tried" mean? Are you getting errors? What is the error? etc.

Comment: When i tried to open the connection ,getting error message as "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to connect your application running on local machine with MySQL running on OpenShift. This will not work as you can't connect with MySQL database from outside OpenShift application gear. You have to use port forwarding to connect to MySQL database. To port-forward, use the `rhc port-forward --app <app_name>` command. rhc is command line client to work with OpenShift. It is a ruby gem that you can install by typing `gem install rhc`.